# Value of $f(8)$ for a $6$ degree polynomial in $x$.

Tags: functions, polynomials, contest-math

$f(x)$ is a $6^{th}$ degree polynomial of $x$. It is given that $f(0)
= 0,f(1) = 1,f(2) = 2,f(3) = 3,f(4) = 4,f(5) = 5$ and $f(6) = 7$ then find the value of $f(8)$.

My solution approach :-
I assumed the polynomial to be $f(x)=ax^6+bx^5+cx^4+dx^3+ex^2+fx+k$ and then by using  $f(0)
= $ we can say that $k=0$ and then I tried using the other values of the function given for $x=1,2,3,4,5$ and $6$ to find out the values of $a,b,c,d,e$ and $f$ but this wasn't a good approach as things became cumbersome and I wasn't able to proceed further in this problem.
Please help me on this!!!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hint: Can you find a modification of $f(x)$ - say $g(x)$ where $g(x)$ has nice roots you can work with?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers down but all have come with a equation of the form $f(x)=x+g(x)$ and I am not able to understand how it has come? What is the thing that I don't know about how to get to this equation?

Comment: Suppose you have a high degree polynomial $f(x)$ which takes values at a number of data points $f(x_i)=y_i$. Say there are $r$ of these points, and suppose also there is a low degree polynomial which also has $h(x_i)=y_i$. Then you could consider $g(x)=f(x)-h(x)$ where $g(x_i)=0$ at each of the data points and hence $g(x)$ has a number of factors $x-x_i$. Here we can spot $h(x)=x$.

Answer (score 4):

Let$$p(x)=\frac1{720}x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5).$$Then $p(n)=0$ if $n\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $p(6)=1$. So, $p(n)+n=f(n)$ when $n\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Since  both $f(x)$ and $p(x)+x$ are $6$<sup>th</sup> degree polynomials, they're equal. So, $f(8)=p(8)+8=36$.

Comment: The final number is not correct.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos : How have you come up with that equation "$p(x)"$

Comment: First of all, $p(x)$ is not an equation; it's a polynomial. And I was after the simplest polynomial with degree $6$ such that $p(x)=0$ when $x\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. First I took $x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)$ but since this takes the value $720$ when $x=6$, I decided to divide it by $720$ in order to work with smaller numbers.

Answer (score 3):

If $x\mapsto f(x)$ is polynomial of degree $d>0$, then $x\mapsto f(x+1)-f(x)$ is polynomial of degree $d-1$. As we are given $f(x)$ at several consecutive integers, repeatedly taking the difference sequence will help us:
$$\begin{array}c\deg&f(0)&&f(1)&&f(2)&&f(3)&&f(4)&&f(5)&&f(6)&&f(7)&&f(8)\\6&0&&1&&2&&3&&4&&5&&7&&?&&?\\5&
&1&&1&&1&&1&&1&&2&&?&&?\\4&&&0&&0&&0&&0&&1&&?&&?\\3&
&&&0&&0&&0&&1&&?&&?\\2&&&&&0&&0&&1&&?&&?\\1&&&&&&0&&1&&?&&?\\0&&&&&&&1&&?&&?\end{array}$$
Can you fill in all "?", given that the last row is degree zero, i.e., constant?

Comment: What is this method called? As I am not a mathematics student, maybe you can tell me about this and I'll study about this? And can you please complete this solution so that I can understand more clearly?

Comment: If I take first $?$ of $f(7)$ to be $x$ and second $?$ of $f(8)$ to be $y$ then at the last it comes to for degree $0$ to be $1, x-13, y-6x+51$ going by the pattern of difference you have proceeded with? How to proceed from there?

Comment: @Ganit This is generally called the method of differences or the method of finite differences - others may have different names.

Comment: What will be the solution for this? At the last I came with 1, x-13, y-6x+51 as I mentioned in the previous comment. How can we proceed from there?

Comment: @Ganit If you know that degree $0$ is $1$, then you can go from bottom to top left to right, calculating the missing one value of a triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the theory:

Polynomials $f(x)$ satisfying

$\quad f(0) = 0,f(1) = 1,f(2) = 2,f(3) = 3,f(4) = 4,f(5) = 5$

can be written as $f(x) = x + g(x)$ where

$\quad g(x) = x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5) h(x)$

Since $f$ is of degree six $h(x)$ must be a constant, say $u$.

So $f(x) = x + u \cdot x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)$

Plugging in,

$\quad f(6) = 7 = 6 + u \cdot 6!$

so $u = \frac{1}{720}$ and

$\quad f(8) = 8 + \frac{1}{720} \frac{8!}{2} = 8 + \frac{20160}{720} = 36$

Comment: This is the best explanation so far, however the "can be written as" should be completed with why there is no other way of getting those function values, otherwise there are other possible values of $f(8)$.